# Standard vs explicit auto-deduced variable declaration

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider these two equivalent variable declarations :

```
int foo{5};
auto bar = int{5};
```

Are there any advantages to using the latter syntax?

Comment: GOTW: https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks!

Comment: I prefer not to use auto unless it's necessary. I'm old-fashioned enough to value printouts of code as a good debugging tool especially when tracing code back to mathematics papers. Having autos everywhere is unhelpful for that cf. an ide where the type is given to you by the debugger.

Comment: Note that the latter syntax does not work with non-copyable and non-movable types, e.g. lock_guard, atomic...

Answer (score 1):

Prefer the **first syntax** cause in **first case** no additional copy, but in **second case** we have a creation of temporary object and then copy this object to original variable **bar**. But it is only in case disabled **copy elison**

With disabled **copy elison**:

```
int foo{5}; // No temporary object
auto bar = int{5}; // Created temporary object and then it is copied in bar
```

With enabled **copy elison**:

```
int foo{5}; // No difference with the second line
auto bar = int{5}; // No difference with the first line
```

Comment: It depends on the compiler optimizations.

Comment: This point is almost moot.  First off it is copy initialized from a direct values so no copy will exist.  Secondly if one was made most of the time it will be moved/elided.  Thirdly in C++ 17 with guaranteed copy elision there will be no copies at all and direct initialization will happen.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I complitly agree with you, but Jérémi P. wants a deep answer and I gave him it

Answer (score -1):

In this example no. You need to use new syntax with a complicated types. I.e., inside for loop with iterators or templates definition.
Compare:

```
vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};

for (auto x : v) std::cout << x << ' ' << std::endl;
```

and:

```
vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};

for (std::vector<int>::iterator x = v.begin(); x != v.end(); ++x) std::cout << x << ' ' << std::endl;
```

Comment: This is not the point of the question. I am asking if declaring an auto-deduced variable with an **explicit type** has any advantages over a standard declaration (without auto). NathanOlivier has answered me.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. It's my inattention.